# Android app crashes, why?

Tags: android, fatal-error

I am trying to create a simple Android app that will have the possibility to fetch the source code of a website.
Anyways, I have written the following:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
try {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());          
    InputStream input = (InputStream) new URL(url.toString()).getContent();
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<html><body><p>"+input.toString()+"</p></body></html>", "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString(),""); 
    //setContentView(webView);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error fetching data", e.getMessage());
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:701)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at com.myprogram.myprogram.Alert.<init>(Alert.java:11)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at com.myprogram.myprogram.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:84)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-11 01:37:59.234: E/AndroidRuntime(28992):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 01:38:21.484: I/Process(28992): Sending signal. PID: 28992 SIG: 9
12-11 01:38:32.739: E/Trace(29922): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-11 01:38:32.939: I/webclipboard(29922): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42209de8
12-11 01:38:32.964: V/webkit(29922): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42204f18}
```

I can't seem to find a solution; what is my problem?

Comment: Did you check the id if it's correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it: Instead of `getApplicationContext()` use `this`

Comment: I've commented it out, but the code won't do anything. Do you have any clue of what would fix it? (the webview is blank)

Comment: <ActivityName>.this - does work, but can you see what is the problem?

Comment: Did you uncomment `setContentView(webView);` ?:>

Comment: Yes I did uncomment it showed the error dialog... I will choose your answer because the current problem seems to be relevant to another question, thanks anyways!